# how to perform a pandas dataframe subsetting using index and assign it a same value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, substring

How to partially split a dataset from row indexes, and column names or column indexes.
I tried this  `df.loc[[1,2,34,'name']] = 100` and `df.iloc[np.where(df.loc[,'name']<100)]=100` this do not work. Need help, thank you!

data sample:

```py
>> df

>>    name  lag
  0   100.0 0.000000
  1   80.0  0.011161
  2   255.0 0.022321
  3   93.0  0.033482
  4   100.0  0.044643
  5   9.8  0.055804
  6   29.0  0.066964
```

Comment: Can you ad some small data sample to question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need set index values `1,2,34` and columns name `name` to `100` use:

```
df.loc[[1,2,34],'name'] = 100
```

If need set by mask use:

```
df.loc[df['name']<100, 'name']=100

#for set another column
df.loc[df['name']<100, 'lag']=100
```